# MXSegmentedPager overlaps with TableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, parallax

Segmented Pager Adapter is overlapping with my TableView when creating it manually

Using following library
https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager

Following is my code

```
let tabVC = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
       "aboutReviewViewControllerID") as! AboutReviewViewController
        viewControllerArray.append(tabVC)
        segmentedPager = MXSegmentedPager(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
       self.view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        view.addSubview(segmentedPager)
        segmentedPager.dataSource = self
        segmentedPager.delegate = self
        segmentedPager.backgroundColor = .clear
        segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.view = topBGView
        segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.mode = .fill
        segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.height = topBGView.frame.height
        segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.minimumHeight = 10
        segmentedPager.parallaxHeader.delegate = self
        segmentedPager.reloadData()


[![enter image description here][1]][1]func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, viewForPageAt index: Int) -> UIView {
    return viewControllerArray[index].view
}

func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, segueIdentifierForPageAt index: Int) -> String {
    return  ""
}
```

[image]